# jQuery .show() / .hide() Not Working in Social Rollover

Tags: jquery, html

So, I'm trying to create a social media rollover, but for some reason, I cannot get it to work. I'm trying to get it to, when I click a link, display a div full of social media icons with links (preferably with a nice animation, but I haven't attempted that yet, since this won't work). I'd rather use jQuery toggle, but, I can't even get this to work, so it seems pointless to attemt something more complicated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rollover Test</title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #one {
            background-image: url('fb.png');
        }
        #two {
            background-image: url('twt.png');
        }
        #three {
            background-image: url('g+.png');
        }
        #four {
            background-image: url('rss.png');
        }
        #five {
            background-image: url('irc.png');
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#socialS').hide();
            $('#clickElement').click(function() {
                $('#socialS').show();
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="socialS">
    <a href=""><div id="one"></div></a>
    Test

    <a href=""><div id="two"></div></a>

    <a href=""><div id="three"></div></a>

    <a href=""><div id="four"></div></a>

    <a href=""><div id="five"></div></a>

</div>

<a href="" id="clickElement">Click me!</a>
Test

</body>
</html>
```

Could I have some assistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mistake in javascript code

```
$(function() {
      $('#socialS').hide();
      $('#clickElement').click(function(e) {
           // make sure you preventing browser to follow link
           e.preventDefault();
           $('#socialS').show();
      }); // was missing brackets
});
```

Always check console for errors.

**UPDATE**

Most simple way to toggle is to use `toggle` feature, i.e.

```
$('#socialS').toggle('fade');
```

The above will also provide animation. I would suggest you also update css accordingly

```
// Always choose `css` instead of javascript where possible.    
#socialS {
    display: none;
}
```

Now you can do something like this, no need to make `#socialS` element hidden manually.

```
      // caching element
      var $social = $('#socialS');
      $('#clickElement').click(function(e) {
          // make sure you preventing browser to follow link
          e.preventDefault();
          $social.toggle('fade');
      });
```

to get more details on jQuery `toggle` command, visit this link http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Great, but how can I toggle it back and forth?